# Fluent NHibernate Mapping a join table without a primary key

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have an existing database that has three tables, two entity tables and a link table.  Each of the two entity tables have a primary key, id.  One uses an int and one uses a guid.  The join table contains two columns, the primary key of each table.  So, roughly it looks like this:

Table 1: Question
Id - primary key, int

### ...

Table 2: Asset
Id - primary key, guid

### ...

Table 3: QuestionAsset

Asset - (PK, FK guid)

Question - (PK, FK, int)

I have my classes setup as follows:

```
public class NQuestion
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual IList<NQuestionAsset> Assets { get; set; }
}

public class NQuestionAsset
{
    public virtual NAsset Asset { get; set; }
    public virtual NQuestion Question { get; set; }
}

public class NAsset
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class QuestionMap : ClassMap<NQuestion>
{
    public QuestionMap()
    {
        Table("Question");
        LazyLoad();

        Id(q => q.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity().Column("Id");
        ...
        HasManyToMany(x => x.Assets).Table("QuestionAsset")
            .ParentKeyColumns.Add("Asset", "Question")
            .Not.LazyLoad();
     }
 }

 public class QuestionAssetMap : ClassMap<NQuestionAsset>
    {
    public QuestionAssetMap()
    {
        Table("QuestionAsset");
        LazyLoad();

        CompositeId().KeyProperty(a => a.Asset, "Id").KeyProperty(a => a.Question, "QuestionId");

        References(a => a.Asset.Id).Column("Asset");
        References(a => a.Question.QuestionId).Column("Question");
    }
}

public class AssetMap : ClassMap<NAsset>
{
    public AssetMap()
    {
        Table("Asset");
        LazyLoad();

        Id(q => q.Id).GeneratedBy.GuidComb().Column("Id");
        ...
    }
}
```

I have tried more iterations of relationships than I care to admit to get the link table to populate.  How do I define this relationship?  I can't change the database.

Right now, with the code above I am getting the following exception:

> Could not determine type for: Question.Model.NHibernate.NAsset, Question, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, for columns: NHibernate.Mapping.Column(Id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case,

- the pairing table does **not** have its own **ID** column
- has only two columns, foreign keys

We should **not** introduce the pairing object, and **just map both ends directly**

```
public class NQuestion
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    ...
    //public virtual IList<NQuestionAsset> Assets { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Asset> Assets { get; set; }
```

and the `HasManyToMany` will work

```
public QuestionMap()
{
    ...
    HasManyToMany(x => x.Assets)
         .Table("QuestionAsset")
         .ParentKeyColumn("Asset")
         .ChildKeyColumn("Question")
         ...;
```

See more here

- https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Fluent-mapping
- http://notherdev.blogspot.cz/2012/01/mapping-by-code-onetomany-and-other.html (second part of the article)

Comment: When I do this, (I created a class called AssetTest) I get the following exception:
An association from the table QuestionAsset refers to an unmapped class: Question.Model.NHibernate.AssetTest

Comment: Of course, you **MUST** map the second part ASSET.. (similar as Question)